# Missing convert_trajectory_transformer_original_pytorch_checkpoint_to_pytorch.py (notebook/Jupyter/transformers)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers

I tried on a notebook to install the package transformers, it failed:

`!pip install transformers`

I get this:

```
FULLTRACE:
Collecting transformers
  Obtaining dependency information for transformers from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/dd/f17b11a93a9ca27728e12512d167eb1281c151c4c6881d3ab59eb58f4127/transformers-4.35.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached transformers-4.35.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (123 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (3.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: huggingface-hub<1.0,>=0.16.4 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: regex!=2019.12.17 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (2023.10.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tokenizers<0.19,>=0.14 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: safetensors>=0.3.1 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.27 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from transformers) (4.66.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from huggingface-hub<1.0,>=0.16.4->transformers) (2023.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from huggingface-hub<1.0,>=0.16.4->transformers) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from tqdm>=4.27->transformers) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\x\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from requests->transformers) (2023.5.7)
Using cached transformers-4.35.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
Installing collected packages: transformers
```

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\transformers\\models\\deprecated\\trajectory_transformer\\convert_trajectory_transformer_original_pytorch_checkpoint_to_pytorch.py'
HINT: This error might have occurred since this system does not have Windows Long Path support enabled. You can find information on how to enable this at https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/enable-long-paths


[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.1
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If you need more details, I'm ready !
I need to write more because the website ask me to. But I don't need to flood you with more info I think.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to load transformers onto my local system and had the same error. (Windows 11 Home)

I opened Registry Editor, navigated to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem

found the value:

LongPathsEnabled

then changed the value from 0 to 1. (hexadecimal, which should be default)

How: Right click the value, select Modify, make the change to "Value Data" in the provided popup window, then click OK. Simple.

Now I can use long paths, which means that the transformers download is working properly. I verified that it works by finding the referenced folder, and seeing that the missing file was installed correctly, following this edit.

Hope this helps.